# JPA ID GeneratedValue is using Oracle nextValue sequence instead of next value

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a spring boot application using hibernate as it's ORM framework. It exposes a RESTful API, one of the methods inserts new messages into the table.

The problem I am having is that it performs a call to Oracle to retrieve the nextval for the sequence number, then when it inserts that it uses the first number from that pool, then when another requests comes in, it takes the value of the next nextval instead of using the next value from the initial pool. So it should go 100, 101, 102, etc... but instead it goes like that 100,200,300 (the allocation size is 100).

All the beans are singletons including the DAO that persists the messages.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGE")
public class Message implements Serializable {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MESSAGEID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SEQ_MESSAGE", allocationSize = 100)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "MESSAGEID_GENERATOR", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "MESSAGEID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10)
private Long messageid;

}
```

Dao:

```
@Repository
public class MessageDao {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ORM_Model")
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

@Transactional
public long save(Message message) {
    entityManager.persist(message);
    entityManager.flush();
    return message.getMessageid();
}
}
```

persistance.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="ORM_Model"> 

    <description>The IFIS Database Entity Model</description>

    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>com.package.Message</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />                 
    </properties>

</persistence-unit> 

</persistence>
```

Any idea what could be the problem here?

Regards!

Comment: Did you by any chance restart your application between the inserts? I have not used Oracles native sequence, but when you use table generated IDs, JPA pre-allocates the next 100 (allocationSize) ids, when you restart your application, your IDs start at the next 100.

Comment: No, this is constant behaviour - I can send two HTTP requests to create the entities and it does increase it by a 100 each time. I thought that this has something to do with different threads and each one separately querying the next sequence value, but every single instance dealing with the DB is by default a singleton, and all of them are part of one application.

Comment: It sounds wrong to me. `allocationSize` is supposed to be the number of ids that JPA will pre-allocate and keep in memory, and it should use all those ids before pre-allocating new ids from the sequence. At least that's how it works with `TableGenerator` which is (more or less) a database agnostic version of the `SequenceGenerator`.

Comment: When I execute that differently using a JUnit and use that method twice to insert, then the ids are assigned on incremental basis, but once this is wrapped with a RESTful controller then it does that by 100s. Is there anything else that is impacting this?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `allocationSize=1` to solve your issue.

Comment: `allocationSize=1` means JPA will do a select NEXT_SEQUENCE for every insert, which can have performance implications. The pre-allocated ids are held in memory, so ID should only reset to the next 100 when you restart you application.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to change the allocationSize, as this sequence is used by different applications I don't want to increase the load for the sequence query. Is there anything else that I should look into?